# Is it possible to quantize a tflite model?

Tags: android, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite, firebase-mlkit

I have a .pb model, which I want to use as a custom MLKit model. MLKit only supports .tflite models, but even after I use `toco` to get the TensorFlow Lite model, the file size is too large for Firebase (95 MB and only 40 MB allowed).

Is there a way to quantize the graph and then convert to TFLite or quantize a .tflite graph?

When I do the former, I get the following error message: `Unsupported TensorFlow op: Dequantize) for which the quantized form is not yet implemented. Sorry, and patches welcome (that's a relatively fun patch to write, mostly providing the actual quantized arithmetic code for this op).`

Answer (score 5):

Since you are primarily interested in reducing model size, you can pass the `--optimizations=[tf.lite.Optimizations.DEFAULT]` flag to TOCO. This should store weights at 8 bits and dequantize during to inference to do floating point computations. Depending on the model and the problem this may have some accuracy implications, so be to run eval on the result model and make sure its up to your desired standards.

If you want to run the model with integer computations you can train with quantization and convert the resulting graph with TOCO to TFLite, using these training rewrites: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/contrib/quantize

This is a bit more involved, and involves doing some retraining on your tensorflow model before freezing and providing to TOCO.

Comment: Using this flag results in a Zero KB graph when I run it.